# which versions of ssl and tls can we use for java 1.2

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2

The Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) and Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocols is integrated from java 1.4. I would like to know which SSL/TLS versions can be used with java 1.2.

Comment: Have you considered upgrading your Java version?

Comment: I *started* Java when 1.2 came out. It should be as dead as I am inside these days.

Comment: Not anytime soon. I am trying to add ssl/tls support to my existing application.

Comment: Why won't you update the version? It would make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which versions of ssl and tls can we use for java 1.2

None. As you correctly state, built-in support for SSL started with Java 1.4. It therefore follows with some considerable immediacy that Java 1.2 does not support TLS out of the box.

If you're very lucky you may still be able to find the separate JSSE download for 1.2, but it won't go beyond TLS 1.0 at the latest, given the dates of all the elements concerned.

You are fifteen years out of date. Upgrade.